# std::ostringstream woes

Tags: c++

I can do

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << 1;
oss.str();
```

so why can't I do:

```
((std::ostringstream()) << 1).str() ?
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540831/stringstream-temporary-ostream-return-problem for interesting issues with the use of temporary stringstreams.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `<<` operator returns the base type `ostream`, while the `str` member function exists only on the derived type `ostringstream`.

Comment: (oss<<1).str() fails the same way. ostream doesnt support str()

Comment: could you cast it back up to an ostringstream?